# Why MX record is not updating the correct A record

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I've notice about cache in the ISP's but i wish know more about this and how to deal with that.

I have more of 24 hours waiting my MX record update to the correct IP. Look this:

[image]

I have an 5 priority for `mail.vuelosenglobos.mx` and the IP Adress it's wrong, and for the 10 priority record the IP it's correct.

Is this a cache issue or it's something else which is causing the first record it's not updading this IP Adress correctly? Actually my domain `descubreteotihuacan.com` it's working very well, but the `MX` record doesn't.

This is my DNS records of my domain:
[image]

This is the DNS records of my hostname
[image]

I have for `descubreteotihuacan.com` domain an TTL of 3600 which is 1 hour i want to update it. Sometimes i think i need to update also the TTL of my hostname `mail.vuelosenglobos.mx` but first i want to make sure it's nothing else.

Thank you.

> It's very important to tell you i use no-ip DNS service because i have dynamic public IP address so that's why i definitely don't use an specific public ip.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that your TTL is lower than the 24 hs from the change, it should be applied by now.

The only problem i see, is that you do not have a type A record `mail.vuelosenglobos.mx -> some ip address` in the DNS zone for the domain vuelosenglobos.mx so, where are you updating it? Add a type A record with the proper IP address and it should work.

in addition of this, the DNS system works using a hyerarchical cache system, with parts that are out of your control. For example some ISPs cache content far longer than others.

You can check if your changes are propagated using tools like [DNSCHECKER](https://dnschecker.org/#MX/descubreteotihuacan.com) and you can force some DNS services to update making some changes instant for a large group of people.

[Flush Google Public DNS cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/cache)

[Flush Cloudflare 1.1.1.1 cache](https://cloudflare-dns.com/purge-cache/)

Edit: I don't have enough reputation to comment, so i will edit.

Glad it worked, the strange part is that mail.vuelosenglobos.mx never appeared to me.

In the DNS Zone of vuelosenglobos.mx you need to have declared two records, one mail.vuelosenglobos.mx pointing to the IP address of your mail server, and a MX record for vuelosenglobos.mx pointing to mail.vuelosenglobos.mx so i don't quite understand how its working now.

[image: Nslookup vuelosenglobos.mx]

Answer (score 0):

Well, after doing what i was suspecting, i remove this from my DNS Records:

[image]

Have sense, because the IP what was showing was the same on this `mail` record `189.139.105.167`. So after deleted it, i could see all the `MX` records of all my server subdomains update to the correct ip, look:

[image]

I did a test sending me an email from other email account and i could recieve it:

[image]

> So, since i'm deealing my DNS with no-ip i've create `mail.vuelosenglobos.mx` hostname from this no-ip service which is always resolving my ISP public ip, so that's why since a beginning i remove the `mail` record from my `primary domain` which is `vuelosenglobos.mx`

Hope this was the solution, but at this moment it's. If you have something else to guide me to do this with a better solution or tell me if i wrong i'll appreciate it.